# I cannot print with HP Laser107a whilst I cannot make hplip to detect it

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, hp

I have an HP Laser107a (https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-100-printer-series/24494339/model/24494340) and because fails to be detected on Ubuntu 18.04 I have installed the latest hplip version from hp website.

As seen on ubuntu's [manual](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) the lsusb shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 03f0:e82a Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But the command `hp-makeuri 03f0:e82a` fails to generate the correct url for my printer:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.12)
Device URI Creation Utility ver. 5.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

error: Device not found
```

Using system settings I manage to add my printer:
[image]

Though I fail to print a pdf file or even a document in libreoffice showing the following error:

[image]

Also, the hp device manager fails to add my printer as well (hplip 3.19.12):

[image]

Do you have any idea why?

Also, using the propriatery driver ofered by hp still shows no light.

Comment: What do you mean by "HP Laserjet 107a"? I can't find anything related on HPLIP [support page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Moreover `03f0:e82a` seems to be [a modem](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Driver-for-USB-VID-03F0-amp-PID-521D-amp-MI-00-7-amp-9341E93/td-p/6243044), not a printer. Did you tried to use USB another cable?

Comment: Sorry it is a Laser107a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work follow these steps:

1. Remove the existing device from the gnome device manager (ommit this step if you setup the printer for first time):
   [image: Remove existing Laset107a reference]
2. Download the driver from hp [website](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-100-printer-series/24494339/model/24494340)
3. Unzip the zipped file.
4. Run the following commands:

```
cd uld
sudo ./install-printer.sh
```

5. On the questions that the install script asks just press y and enter.
6. Then click upon the button shown in the following screen (assume no printer as added).
   [image: Image Settings For printer]
7. Then click add:
   [image: Prompt to add a printer]
8. Then select the printer from an existing database and press forward:
   [image: Select the printer device from the db]
9. And select the `Laser 10x` driver:
   [image: Select Laser Drive]

Please check whether you can ommit steps 2-4 because a propriatery driver is being installed. With the steps above you will be able to print, though `hplip-gui` *won't* be able to detect the printer.

Comment: FYI similar steps can be followed on Linux Mint as well. I tested it upon Linux mint 19.03

Comment: I am having trouble in 20.04. I could sort of follow the procedure, however when I look at the URI I see file:///dev/null.

Comment: This solution does not work at the moment for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Laser 107a does not actually support ipp-usb protocol, so it's necessary to remove packages:
`sudo apt purge ippusbxd ipp-usb`

Comment: Is there a way to place an exception for some printers in CUPS not to use ipp?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an update related to use the printer on Ubuntu 20.04.

Something changed and the printer cannot be found by CUPS. I did not do a deep dive to figure out why or how it happened but purging ippusbxd from the system allowed the printer to be properly found by CUPS and the process using the ULD drivers works as expected

I simply ran

```
sudo apt purge ippusbxd
```

removed any pre-existing instance of a Lase10x printer, and followed the install steps described by Dimitrios