# Using HP Laser 107a with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, hp

I recently bought a HP laser 107a as a budget printer on a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. The reason I bought it was that, I read it was compatible with Linux.

When I received the printed, I tried following the [tutoriallinux guide](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/03/30/how-to-install-hp-laser-107w-107a-driver-on-ubuntu-distro/). So, I downloaded the [uld driver](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-100-printer-series/24494339/model/24494340) from the hp site (at that point I found out that HP Laser 107a was basically a rebranded Samsung printer which used the uld driver).  When I connected the printer to the laptop, although the printer was recognized I was unable to print. Initially, the "Printing Options" dialog was empty and upon closer inspection I realized that there was no PPD.

Then I came across the following [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196925/i-cannot-print-with-hp-laser107a-whilst-i-cannot-make-hplip-to-detect-it) which addresses 18.04 LTS and 19.04. I followed as closely as possible the instructions and I managed to select the proper driver (HP Laser 10x Series), either by selecting the database (initially), or by locating the PPD file in the **/opt/** folder. In either case the result was the same:

- I managed to get the **Printer Options** filed
- I was not able to print. Whenever I sent something to the printer, I got the message that the job was submitted and the completed.

Upon closer inspection I realized that the URI of the printer was "file:///dev/null", which explains why everything was submitted. Also, whenever I  opened the printer dialog from e.g. Libreoffice or a PDF viewer, and I was trying to select the printer, all I got was "Waiting for printer ...". I suspect this might be also be explained by the URI.

My next step, was to find out whether the printer was OK. Initially, I connected it to a Windows machine, and without no problems I got a test page.

The next step was to try another distribution. I tried Manjaro with a 5.4 kernel and followed a similar path with the [tutoriallinux article](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/03/30/how-to-install-hp-laser-107w-107a-driver-on-ubuntu-distro/), running Xcfe. I managed to get the test page without problems or hiccups also. I additionally checked the URI dialog from the CUPS client and saw that the URI was **usb:/HP/[....]**  (i.e. not **file:///dev/null**)

I've also tried the [Debugging Printing Problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) page, with limited success, because I can't get **lpinfo -v** in my Ubuntu 20.04 installation to identify the printer (in Manjaro it was identified).

At this point, I am not sure if its a Ubuntu problem or if its something wrong with my setup from the upgrade or previous HP installations. I would appreciate any guidance on the matter.

**=================UPDATE:=====================**

**lpinfo -v** output (# replaces an A-z0-9)

```
network ipps
network beh
network lpd
network http
file cups-brf:/
direct hp
network https
network ipp
network socket
direct hpfax
network socket://[####:###:####:####:####:####:####:####]
network dnssd://HP%20Officejet%20Pro%208610%20%5B123az%5D._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=1c852a4d-b800-1f08-####-34####
network ipp://HP%20Officejet%20Pro%208610%20%####%5D._ipp._tcp.local/
```

**lpstat -t** output

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: HP_Officejet_Pro_8610_######_
device for HP_Laser_103_107_108: ///dev/null
device for HP_Officejet_Pro_8610_######_: implicitclass://HP_Officejet_Pro_8610_######_/
HP_Laser_103_107_108 accepting requests since Παρ 02 Οκτ 2020 02:55:52 πμ EEST
HP_Officejet_Pro_8610_######_ accepting requests since Παρ 02 Οκτ 2020 02:51:35 πμ EEST
printer HP_Laser_103_107_108 is idle.  enabled since Παρ 02 Οκτ 2020 02:55:52 πμ EEST
printer HP_Officejet_Pro_8610_######_ is idle.  enabled since Παρ 02 Οκτ 2020 02:51:35 πμ EEST
```

**/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb**

```
DEBUG: Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
DEBUG: Loaded 181 quirks.
DEBUG: list_devices
DEBUG: libusb_get_device_list=7
```

**lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7**

```
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0 
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2b8a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 03f0:e82a HP, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**systemctl list-units "ippusbxd*"**

```
  UNIT LOAD ACTIVE SUB DESCRIPTION
0 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Comment: Not being able to get an output from 'lpinfo -v' is quite worrying. Do you have anything from 'lpstat -t'?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I've updated the output of both lpinfo and lpstat after the installation process. There is one more HP Office Deskjet printer which is working properly.

Comment: There isn't any "direct usb" line in the `lpinfo -v` output. Do you get an empty output with `sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb`? A USB URI is required to set up a print queue.

Comment: I updated the post with the output of the /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb. As I think I've mentioned in the post the URI that is automatically assigned is file:///dev/null in Ubuntu, in manjaro I get a proper usb:/HP/etc...

Comment: This is a longshot. Please provide the output of `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`

Comment: Hi, @brian_p I updated the output

Comment: have you tried the "generic" drivers? I will be the first to admit I am no printer expert. But when I went from one version to another and my printer did not work, using the generic driver was the thing that easily got it printing again. I use (again non-expert) the http://localhost:631 page to configure printers and select the generic laser now, even the generic IPP now that I am using network printing. When I need a specific printer, sometimes they arent there, I've had to apt-get printer-driver-gutenprint or openprinting-ppds... there are some hp related, apt-cache search print | grep hp

Comment: Thanks for the `lsusb -v` output. I can see light at the end of the tunnel. Just one more piece of information to make it brighter: give what you get for `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd*" | grep service`.

Comment: The output was null, so I also run systemctl list-units "ippusbxd*"  and I put that up there. If you think you next comment is a solution put it up as an answer :-)

Comment: I also just tried  ```sudo systemctl start ippusbxd``` and I got back 
```Failed to start ippusbxd.service: Unit ippusbxd.service not found.```. Additionally, apt reports that ippusbxd  (1.34-2ubuntu1) is installed.

Comment: The service name is ippusbxd@.service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsusb -v` shows two interfaces with the property

> bInterfaceProtocol      4

This indicates that the printer understands the IPP-over-USB protocol. See [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting). On Ubuntu 20.04 ippusbxd is responsible for IPP-over-USB communication. ippusbxd commandeers the USB interface so that nothing else can use it. That is why `lpinfo -v` does not show a usb URI. Manjaro does not use ippusbxd by default as Ubuntu does.

I would `apt purge ippusbxd`, re-power the printer,  re-plug USB and re-test.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I got my **HP Laser 107a** to work on my freshly installed **Ubuntu 20.04.**

**Step 1:** Remove `ippusbxd` as mentioned in the previous answer.

```
sudo apt purge ippusbxd
```

**Step 2:** Download and install the HP Laser 10x series drivers.

```
wget https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/printers/CLP150/uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz
tar -xvf uld-hp_V1.00.39.12_00.15.tar.gz
cd uld/
sudo ./install.sh
```

**Step 3:** Open `Settings` and remove any existing instance if exists. Select `Additional Printer Settings` and click `Add` on the next screen.

**Step 4:** Select the `HP Laser 103 107 108` option and click `Forward`. This will start searching for drivers. Wait for that to finish.

**Step 5:** On the next screen with `Select printer from database` checked select `HP` from the list and click `Forward`.

**Step 6:** Select the `Laser 10x` option and click `Forward`. On the next screen click `Apply` and it is done! You can print a test page from the next screen to verify the setup.

Comment: A nightmare as usual, but it works and I have no idea how I'd ever get it working without this answer.

Comment: Agree, Laser 10x so unintuitive.

Comment: `sudo apt purge ipp-usb` is also needed for newer versions of Ubuntu

Comment: `sudo /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb` should show the printer and no error if both ipp-usb and ippusbxd are uninstalled.